# Understanding ndarray shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I'm new to numpy and am having trouble understanding how shapes of arrays are decided. 
An array of the form

```
[[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [1,2,4,3]]
```

has a shape of (2,) while one of the form

```
[[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [1,2,4]]
```

has a shape of (2,3). Moreover,

```
[[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [[1,2,4], [3,4,2]]]
```

has a shape of (2,) but adding another vector as

```
[[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [[1,2,4], [3,4,2], [1,2,4]]]
```

changes the shape to (2,3,3). Intuitively, I feel that all the arrays should be 3 - dimensional. Could anyone help me understand what's happening exactly?

Comment: It's because you have variable number of elements in each *sublist*, forcing arrays with object dtype, not a *regular* one.

Comment: Upgrade to numpy 1.13.x, and these object arrays will be printed less confusingly

Comment: `numpy` does not support "jagged arrays", only true multidimensional arrays. Thus when the constructor detects that your sublists would produce a jagged array, it creates a one-dimensional array of Python objects.

Comment: This question comes up time and time again - is there a canonical question/answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying idea is that `np.array` tries to create as high a dimensional array as it can.  When the sublists have matching numbers of elements the result is easy to see.  When they mix lists of differing lengths the result can be confusing.

In your first case you have 2 sublists, one of length 3, the other length 4.  So it makes a 2 element object array, and doesn't try to parse the sublists of the 1st sublist

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [1,2,4,3]])
In [2]: arr
Out[2]: array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], 
               [1, 2, 4, 3]
              ], dtype=object)   # adjusted format
In [3]: arr.dtype
Out[3]: dtype('O')
In [4]: arr.shape
Out[4]: (2,)
In [5]: arr[0]
Out[5]: [[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]] # 3 element list of lists
In [6]: arr[1]
Out[6]: [1, 2, 4, 3]  # 4 element list of numbers
```

In the 2nd case you have two sublists, both of length 3.  So it makes a 2x3 array.  But one sublist contains lists, the other numbers - so the result is again object array:

```
In [7]: arr = np.array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [1,2,4]] )
In [8]: arr
Out[8]: 
array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]],
       [1, 2, 4]
      ], dtype=object)
In [9]: arr.shape
Out[9]: (2, 3)
In [10]: arr[0,0]
Out[10]: [5, 10, 15]
```

Finally, 2 lists, each with 3 elements, each of which is also 3 element lists - a 3d array.

```
In [11]: arr = np.array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [[1,2,4], [3,4,2], [1,2,4]]] )
In [12]: arr
Out[12]: 
array([[[ 5, 10, 15],
        [20, 25, 30],
        [35, 40, 45]],

       [[ 1,  2,  4],
        [ 3,  4,  2],
        [ 1,  2,  4]]])
In [13]: arr.shape
Out[13]: (2, 3, 3)
```

There are also mixes of sublist lengths that can raise an error.

In general don't mix sublists of differing size and content type casually.  `np.array` behaves most predictably when given lists that will produce a nice multidimensional array.  Mixing list lengths leads to confusion.

---

Updated numpy:

```
In [1]: np.__version__
Out[1]: '1.13.1'
In [2]: np.array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [1,2,4,3]])
Out[2]: array([list([[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]]), list([1, 2, 4, 3])], dtype=object)

In [3]: np.array([[[5, 10, 15], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]], [1,2,4]] )
Out[3]: 
array([[list([5, 10, 15]), list([20, 25, 30]), list([35, 40, 45])],
       [1, 2, 4]], dtype=object)
```

It now identifies the `list` elements

This last example is still (2,3) object array.  As such each of those 6 elements could be a different Python type, e.g.:

```
In [11]: np.array([[[5, 10, 15], np.array([20, 25, 30]), (35, 40, 45)], [None,2,'astr']] )
Out[11]: 
array([[list([5, 10, 15]), array([20, 25, 30]), (35, 40, 45)],
       [None, 2, 'astr']], dtype=object)
In [12]: [type(x) for x in _.flat]
Out[12]: [list, numpy.ndarray, tuple, NoneType, int, str]
```